# R data compilation(sorting out or data manipulation)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-extraction

here is my excel csv data(test.csv):

```
type,com,year,month,value
A,CH,2015,1,1000
A,CH,2015,2,5000
A,CH,2016,1,1500
A,MI,2015,1,1300
A,MI,2016,1,5006
B,CH,2015,1,7651
B,CH,2015,2,8684
B,MI,2016,1,2321
B,ZU,2015,1,6842
C,CH,2015,1,1562
C,CH,2016,2,6452
C,CH,2016,3,1562
C,MI,2016,1,6425
C,MI,2016,2,2682
C,ZU,2015,1,8543
C,ZU,2015,2,7531
```

how can I extract each `type` to each data frame with R.  
To be more concise, I mean I want to build 3 new data frame(typeA, typeB and typeC). And how can I combine year and month into one so I can plot with **ggplot2**.

Here is an additional question: Where can I find some reference about sorting out data which is similar to the above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data =read.csv("test.csv", header=T)
dataA = data[which(data$type =="A"),]
dataB = data[which(data$type =="B"),]
dataC = data[which(data$type =="C"),]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a more common sense:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
df_list <- split(df, factor(df$type))
```

Every entry in `df_list` is now a new data.frame with one type, e.g. `df_list[[1]` or `df_list$A`.

Comment: thanks. Can I ask additional question? how can I combine year and month into one so I can plot with ggplot2 that x=year+month , y=value, colour=com?

Comment: sorry. I got some warning message. 
[Warning message:
In grepl("|||", what, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 1 is invalid in this locale]. 
Although it still works and splits to each, I still want to realize why I got this warning message. Probabaly because my data contains Chinese?